# PredictionIO IntelliJ setup. Missing module SDK

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, predictionio

I'm trying to setup IntelliJ Idea for PredictionIO engine development in Scala. I'm following the [documentation](https://docs.prediction.io/resources/intellij/) step by step. However, I am unable to build the project due to missing SDK.

[image]

I have JDK installed. Should I point to this SDK there? Thanks for help!

Comment: did you install the scala SDK and sbt?

Comment: I installed Scala Plugin for IntelliJ. The SDKs dropdown is empty.

Comment: Did you restart your IDE?

Comment: Yes, just now, nothing shows up. What should show up there?

Comment: Did you try right-click on the project > Add Framework Support? Did you install Scala and Java on your system?

Comment: I installed Java. I didn't install Scala, just the Scala plugin for IntelliJ. When I go to `Add Framework Support` I see to options there `Maven` and `Groovy`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83133/discussion-between-eliasah-and-bear-with-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because the SDK of Scala is missing. Installing the plugin of Scala in IntelliJ is not enough. There are two ways to solve this:

1. Install Scala in your computer and fill the right path of Scala in the field of SDK of Scala in IntelliJ.
2. Use IntelliJ to download the SDK of Scala. You can find the download button in the “project settings”.

Please comment if you need more clarification.